# XNA player input process

Tags: c#, input, xna

I have a code that get player input for their name like this (yes, it old-fashioned one)
declare the variable:

```
bool hiScore = false; 

string[] alphabet = new string[] { "_", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h",
       "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", 
       "x", "y", "z" }; 

int ltrCounter1, ltrCounter2, ltrCounter3, ltrCounter4, ltrCounter5; 

string plyrNamePos1, plyrNamePos2, plyrNamePos3, plyrNamePos4, plyrNamePos5; 

int letterPosition = 1;
```

and I make it zero at the beginning of the class

```
ltrCounter1 = 0;
ltrCounter2 = 0; 
ltrCounter3 = 0;
ltrCounter4 = 0;
ltrCounter5 = 0;
plyrNamePos1 = alphabet[0];
plyrNamePos2 = alphabet[0];
plyrNamePos3 = alphabet[0];
plyrNamePos4 = alphabet[0];
plyrNamePos5 = alphabet[0]
```

and in the `update()` method I placed this code to grab the arrow keys and with them, change the letters.

```
keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

if (CheckKey(Keys.Up))
{
    hiScoreUp();
}
else if (CheckKey(Keys.Down))
{
    hiScoreDown();
}

if (CheckKey(Keys.Right))
{
    letterPosition++;
    if (letterPosition > 5)
    {
        letterPosition = 5;
    }
}
else if (CheckKey(Keys.Left))
{
    letterPosition--;
    if (letterPosition < 1)
    {
        letterPosition = 1;
    }
}
else if (CheckKey(Keys.Enter))
{
    saveHighScores();
    QuizScreen.score = 100;
    ActionScreen.halaman = 1;
    kembalikemenuutama = true;
}
```

and this method to change the letters

```
private void hiScoreUp() 
{ 
    switch (letterPosition) 
    { 
        case 1: 
            ltrCounter1++; 
            if (ltrCounter1 > 26) 
            { 
                ltrCounter1 = 0; 
            } 
            plyrNamePos1 = alphabet[ltrCounter1]; 
            break; 
        case 2: 
            ltrCounter2++; 
            if (ltrCounter2 > 26) 
            { 
                ltrCounter2 = 0; 
            } 
            plyrNamePos2 = alphabet[ltrCounter2]; 
            break; 
        case 3: 
            ltrCounter3++; 
            if (ltrCounter3 > 26) 
            { 
                ltrCounter3 = 0; 
            } 
            plyrNamePos3 = alphabet[ltrCounter3]; 
            break; 
        case 4: 
            ltrCounter4++; 
            if (ltrCounter4 > 26) 
            { 
                ltrCounter4 = 0; 
            } 
            plyrNamePos4 = alphabet[ltrCounter4]; 
            break; 
        case 5: 
            ltrCounter5++; 
            if (ltrCounter5 > 26) 
            { 
                ltrCounter5 = 0; 
            } 
            plyrNamePos5 = alphabet[ltrCounter5]; 
            break; 
    } 
} 

private void hiScoreDown() 
{ 
    switch (letterPosition) 
    { 
        case 1: 
            ltrCounter1--; 
            if (ltrCounter1 < 0) 
            { 
                ltrCounter1 = 26; 
            } 
            plyrNamePos1 = alphabet[ltrCounter1]; 
            break; 
        case 2: 
            ltrCounter2--; 
            if (ltrCounter2 < 0) 
            { 
                ltrCounter2 = 26; 
            } 
            plyrNamePos2 = alphabet[ltrCounter2]; 
            break; 
        case 3: 
            ltrCounter3--; 
            if (ltrCounter3 < 0) 
            { 
                ltrCounter3 = 26; 
            } 
            plyrNamePos3 = alphabet[ltrCounter3]; 
            break; 
        case 4: 
            ltrCounter4--; 
            if (ltrCounter4 < 0) 
            { 
                ltrCounter4 = 26; 
            } 
            plyrNamePos4 = alphabet[ltrCounter4]; 
            break; 
        case 5: 
            ltrCounter5--; 
            if (ltrCounter5 < 0) 
            { 
                ltrCounter5 = 26; 
            } 
            plyrNamePos5 = alphabet[ltrCounter5]; 
            break; 
    } 
}
```

and this is how I draw it

```
hiScoreName = plyrNamePos1 + " " + plyrNamePos2 + " " + plyrNamePos3 + " " + 
      plyrNamePos4 + " " + plyrNamePos5;

if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds % 1000 < 500)
{
    spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, hiScoreName, new Vector2(350, 280), 
    Color.Blue);
}
```

what I want to ask is :

1. How I can make the active field of that input field blink?
   with the current code, I only can make all of the field blink (using `gameTime.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds % 1000 < 500` for the drawstring).
2. I'm using `"_"` to fill-in for space `" "`. And when the player name data saved, the `"_"` is also saved in the database. How can I make the `"_"` change to `" "`, when it saved to the outer source...?
3. How I can display an alert message to the player when they tried to save the player name with `"_"` character in all field...?

Can anyone help...?

Sorry if this quite long.
And thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay...

1)
Instead of displaying a string that consists of all the characters, you could draw individual characters next to each other

```
hiScoreName = plyrNamePos1 + plyrNamePos2 + plyrNamePos3 + plyrNamePos4 + plyrNamePos5;

int characterSpacing = 20; //might be more or less for you

for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
    if(i==letterposition){
        if(gameTime.TotalGameTime.Miliseconds % 1000 < 500){
            spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, hiScoreName[i-1], new Vector(350 + (i-1)*characterSpacing, 280), Color.Blue);
        }
    }else{
        spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, hiScoreName[i-1], new Vector(350 + (i-1)*characterSpacing, 280), Color.Blue);
    }
}
```

note: i just typed this code in here, never tested it so it might have some bugs :)

2)
You could use `String.Replace()` method.

```
String stringToSave = hiScoreName.Replace("_"," ");
```

3)
When you detect that all the characters are _, you should set a flag (a bool variable lets say) in your program that indicates that player tried to save as all _. Then in your draw method, you could display your message if this flag is set. When player then changes a character, the flag should be reset.

```
bool _invalidHiScoreName = false; //somewhere outside methods.

void SavePlayerScore(String hiScoreName, int score){
    bool allUnderscore = true;
    foreach(char c in hiScoreName){
        if(c!='_')
            allUnderscore = false;
    }

    if(allUnderscore){
        _invalidHiScoreName = true;
    }else{
        String stringToSave = hiScoreName.Replace("_"," "); //from step 2)
        //your saving logic.
    }
}
```

Then, in your draw method, between `spriteBatch.Begin()` and `spriteBatch.End()` you could put:

```
if(_invalidHiScoreName){
    spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, "Hi Score Name must have at least one character!", Vector2.Zero, Color.White); //Might wanna position it.
}
```

Don't forget to reset the flag `_invalidHiScoreName=false;` when a character is changed!

Other than that, I could tell you that this is a really bad way to get input and suggest other more simpler/better ways, but that doesn't really answer the question and I also hate it when people don't answer the question :)

Have fun.

Comment: I tried that, for the first one it get error. I think the error from hiScoreName[i-1]. But I don't know why. and for the 2nd, where must I put that String stringToSave = hiScoreName.Replace("_"," ");...?

Comment: and yeah I know my way to get name input is quite bad. any other way to do it?
because, I browsed and the only one tutorial I get and worked is only like this

Comment: Hmm, the error on the first one could be because it's a char, not a string (is that the error you're getting?). You could try to put `hiScoreName[i-1]+""` instead, and see what happens.

Comment: For the second one, do you have the code that saves the result? If so, just replace what you would normally save with that, easy!

Comment: As for a different input method, you could just check what keys are being pressed and use them (as in, people could type in the name!) Using the Keyboard.GetState().

Comment: and for the 1st one, yeah the error gone, but the character field that displayed only 3 (the 1st, 3rd, and 5th position). but that 3rd and 5th position not correctly works too, because when I press the up or down button it don't change the character.

Comment: try to increase the character spacing variable and see if it works then? That is the only thing i can think of right now..

Comment: no, the spacing only create a different gap between the char position. and after I checked it again, the char field that been displayed is the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd one. the last two not displayed, but it still get the user input.

Comment: Hmmmm, well it's hard to tell why they aren't being display from all the way over here :) How about you try this, put a breakpoint somewhere at the beginning of the method that draws characters, then press f11 (step through) and go through the for loop that draws each character and see if correct characters are being sent to the drawstring method. Also, try to highlight the hiScoreName String variable after it has been assigned to check if it holds the correct values. You could also try to first change some characters, and THEN put a breakpoint in, to see if the state matches what you see.

Comment: and by 'highlight' the string variable, I mean hover your mouse over it in visual studio. And report back even if you succeed in solving the problem please :)

Comment: I tried it. and the hiScoreName in the drawstring contain right characters. but after I rechecked it again, the field that displayed is indeed the 1st, 3rd, and 5th position. but when the 2nd field active, the blinking goes to the 3rd position. and when the 3rd field active, blinking goes to the 5th position.  and for the 4th and 5th field active, it not displayed although it still get the characters

Comment: Could you doublecheck to see if youre using the code as it's posted here (and in your post), and that there are no differences (for example that in the for loop its i++ and not i+=2). And what does your CheckKey method do btw?

Comment: yes, most of player input method code is same as the one I posted here. and my checkkey method only to check the button state, wheter it's pressed or not.

Comment: Do this: comment out the `hiScoreName = plyrNamePos1 + ...` and manually assign `hiScoreName = "Jonny";` (or anything with 5 characters) and see if it all gets displayed. I have a feeling were missing something really simple here :)

Comment: oh when I try using a string manually like your suggestion, it works perfectly like what I want...hmm I wonder what's wrong with my `hiScoreName = plyrNamePos1 + ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an input solution that is based on **typing**, rather than **selecting characters**.

This code uses native win32 API to detect keystrokes (control characters included).

Code was provided by Promit, a gamedev.net user, [in this post](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/457783-xna-getting-text-from-keyboard/page__view__findpost__p__4040190).

**Create a new class** in your project, name it `CharEventArgs`, and replace everything inside with the following (code from the link above):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace EventInput
{
    public class CharacterEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private readonly char character;
        private readonly int lParam;

        public CharacterEventArgs(char character, int lParam)
        {
            this.character = character;
            this.lParam = lParam;
        }

        public char Character
        {
            get { return character; }
        }

        public int Param
        {
            get { return lParam; }
        }

        public int RepeatCount
        {
            get { return lParam & 0xffff; }
        }

        public bool ExtendedKey
        {
            get { return (lParam & (1 << 24)) > 0; }
        }

        public bool AltPressed
        {
            get { return (lParam & (1 << 29)) > 0; }
        }

        public bool PreviousState
        {
            get { return (lParam & (1 << 30)) > 0; }
        }

        public bool TransitionState
        {
            get { return (lParam & (1 << 31)) > 0; }
        }
    }

    public class KeyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private Keys keyCode;

        public KeyEventArgs(Keys keyCode)
        {
            this.keyCode = keyCode;
        }

        public Keys KeyCode
        {
            get { return keyCode; }
        }
    }

    public delegate void CharEnteredHandler(object sender, CharacterEventArgs e);
    public delegate void KeyEventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e);

    public static class EventInput
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Event raised when a character has been entered.
        /// </summary>
        public static event CharEnteredHandler CharEntered;

        /// <summary>
        /// Event raised when a key has been pressed down. May fire multiple times due to keyboard repeat.
        /// </summary>
        public static event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;

        /// <summary>
        /// Event raised when a key has been released.
        /// </summary>
        public static event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;

        delegate IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        static bool initialized;
        static IntPtr prevWndProc;
        static WndProc hookProcDelegate;
        static IntPtr hIMC;

        //various Win32 constants that we need
        const int GWL_WNDPROC = -4;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
        const int WM_CHAR = 0x102;
        const int WM_IME_SETCONTEXT = 0x0281;
        const int WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE = 0x51;
        const int WM_GETDLGCODE = 0x87;
        const int WM_IME_COMPOSITION = 0x10f;
        const int DLGC_WANTALLKEYS = 4;

        //Win32 functions that we're using
        [DllImport("Imm32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr ImmGetContext(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("Imm32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr ImmAssociateContext(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hIMC);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CallWindowProc(IntPtr lpPrevWndFunc, IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the TextInput with the given GameWindow.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="window">The XNA window to which text input should be linked.</param>
        public static void Initialize(GameWindow window)
        {
            if (initialized)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("TextInput.Initialize can only be called once!");

            hookProcDelegate = new WndProc(HookProc);
            prevWndProc = (IntPtr)SetWindowLong(window.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC,
                (int)Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(hookProcDelegate));

            hIMC = ImmGetContext(window.Handle);
            initialized = true;
        }

        static IntPtr HookProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            IntPtr returnCode = CallWindowProc(prevWndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

            switch (msg)
            {
                case WM_GETDLGCODE:
                    returnCode = (IntPtr)(returnCode.ToInt32() | DLGC_WANTALLKEYS);
                    break;

                case WM_KEYDOWN:
                    if (KeyDown != null)
                        KeyDown(null, new KeyEventArgs((Keys)wParam));
                    break;

                case WM_KEYUP:
                    if (KeyUp != null)
                        KeyUp(null, new KeyEventArgs((Keys)wParam));
                    break;

                case WM_CHAR:
                    if (CharEntered != null)
                        CharEntered(null, new CharacterEventArgs((char)wParam, lParam.ToInt32()));
                    break;

                case WM_IME_SETCONTEXT:
                    if (wParam.ToInt32() == 1)
                        ImmAssociateContext(hWnd, hIMC);
                    break;

                case WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE:
                    ImmAssociateContext(hWnd, hIMC);
                    returnCode = (IntPtr)1;
                    break;
            }

            return returnCode;
        }
    }
}
```

**In your Game1.cs** (or whatever you decided to name it), put the `using EventInput;` on top.

**In your Initialize method**, add the following:

```
EventInput.EventInput.Initialize(this.Window);
EventInput.EventInput.CharEntered += new CharEnteredHandler(EventInput_CharEntered);
```

**In your Game1.cs** (again, what you named it), add the relevant handler:

```
    void EventInput_CharEntered(object sender, CharacterEventArgs e)
    {

        if (char.IsControl(e.Character))
        {
            switch (e.Character)
            {
                case '\b':
                    if (hiScoreName.Length > 0)
                    {
                        hiScoreName = hiScoreName.Substring(0, hiScoreName.Length - 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case '\r':
                    //enter
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            hiScoreName += e.Character;
        }
    }
```

**Finally, in your Draw() method**, use similar code to draw the string:

```
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, hiScoreName, new Vector2(20f, 20f), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.End();
```

Summary:

This pretty much invalidates everything else in this topic (including your code, and everything I posted in the other answer), because it uses a different way to get input from the user.

Once you paste the code in CharEventArgs.cs, you can safely **close it and never open it again**, it will do what it should.

The **main point where you handle input** is your event handler `EventInput_CharEntered`, where you check what character is pressed, and act upon it. You should play with this method, add your own code so that you can for example use it for hiScoreName input in one case, and use it for some other text input in another place.

You can see in the event handler, i commented the //enter, so you could let's say put a function call to handle saving the hiScoreName there!

Also, notice that `CharacterEventArgs e` **contains information about additional modifiers**, such as Alt, repeat count, etc.. You can use those to add additional logic to your program. Useful read about how windows processes keystrokes [on this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (very comprehensible).

You could also register the KeyPressed and KeyReleased events on the EventInput class if you need them.

I tested the code I posted here, and it works for me!

Have fun!

**EDIT**:
If you want to use Unicode characters (that are relevant to your language, i.e. I use ščćžđ), you need to call the DLLImports like so:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

So you have to change all the DllImport calls to include `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode`.

Also, don't forget to extend the range on your spritefont to include those other characters you might want to display.